# How can I use @Async annotation service method inside call Async method? Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

**In below example is a service class with define async method and using Async annotation**

```
@Service
public class ContactServiceImpl implements ContactService {

  @Autowired
  private ContactRepository contactRepository;

  @Override
  public Contact createContact(Contact contact) {
    return contactRepository.save(contact);
  }

  @Override
  public void test() {
    this.t1();
  }

  @Async
  public void t1() {
    try {
      System.out.println("start");
      Thread.sleep(10000l);
      System.out.println("end");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But this seems still running synchronously. What is the problem here?

Comment: This is known as a *self-call*, and since it bypasses the wrapper that Spring uses to apply advice, no Spring advice (including `@Async` and `@Transactional`) is applied.

Comment: Do you add  @EnableAsync on your SpringBootApplication class ?

Comment: Yes it's already there

Comment: `
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class ContactApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ContactApplication, args);
  }
}
`